# Requesting all providers for a bound interface in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to test whether all providers for an interface, that is bound multiple times, are instantiated correctly by my module. To bind in my module I use a Multibinder in Google Guice v3.

I couldn't find a method that returns me all (multiple) providers for a specific interface/class. Using getProvider() only returns a single Provider.

Does anyone have an elegant solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate all bindings from the Injector and check those which match your expected interface.

```
@Inject void checkBindings(Injector injector){
  for(Binding<?> rawbinding : injector.getBindings().values()){
    if (rawbinding instanceof BindingImpl){
      BindingImpl<?> binding = (BindingImpl<?>)rawbinding;
      if (binding.getKey().getTypeLiteral().getRawType() == MyInterface.class){
        ...
```